# Slow page generation in Django with 50+ sql queries per page

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

In my Django app I noticed that pages with big number of sql queries load considerably slower than other pages. I'm not a first day in web dev and mainly I have a deal with such a resource hog as Drupal, but even Drupal with its 150 - 200 sql queries per page generates page in 0.5 - 0.7 sec.

Django from the other side, performs really bad with more or less average number of queries per page. For example, one of my pages generates 60 queries like this:

```
SELECT`gamenode_gamenode`.`id`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`title`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`short_desc`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`full_desc`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`slug`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`type`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`source_gameid`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`created`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`updated`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`status`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`promote`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`sticky`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`hit_count`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`game_rank`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`share_count`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`like_count`, `gamenode_gamenode`.`comment_count` FROM `gamenode_gamenode` WHERE `gamenode_gamenode`.`id` = 1058
```

and outputs the data as a simple string and it takes 1200ms to generate a page! I did this just for a test to generate many fairly simple queries. If I lower the number of queries to 10 - 15, page generation time will come back to more or less acceptable number.

So I have a question, why Django is so slow when there are many sql queries on the page? I did similar comparisons by using Rails, Symfony and Drupal and all these "resource hogs" performed way better than Django. Am I doing something wrong or there's some "secret" setting to make things faster in Django or, maybe, Djangonauts consider such times as normal and just strive to write code which produces as few queries as possible? Please help me to figure this out.

Comment: Sometimes there is. I'm not talking about reasons. I'm talking about the fact. The fact that when you have a little more than a few number of queries on the page, it performs way slow. Not slower, but way slow. And this is not normal in my understanding, especially, when other systems (known as less performant) perform way better. Caching is not appropriate here. I'm talking about raw results.

Comment: Is this test on speed being sone with debug = true and on the development server?

Comment: What DB are you using? Are you in production or development? What's your server setup? What queries are you making on the page via the Django ORM (post your code)? What's in the DB - is there a lot of data? Have you installed something like django-debug-toolbar to see exactly which queries are being created and how long each one is taking?

Comment: Please post code of how you are testing Django. What is your view code? What are your models? What database are you using with how much data? It is impossible to give some useful insights without anything concrete.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Django's ORM is pretty slow. You have three choices for dealing with this:

1. Complain about it.
2. Switch to another web application framework.
3. Make some effort to understand why your application is generating so many database queries, and learn how to use Django's ORM effectively so as to reduce the number of queries.

(1) might be psychologically satisfying but won't solve your problem; (2) is off-topic here at Stack Overflow (but you might look at  Wikipedia's [Comparison of web application frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks)).

We *can* help you with (3), but only if you show us some more of your code. The query you quoted looks like a typical query that Django would generate for a call to [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get):

```
GameNode.objects.get(id = 1058)
```

You shouldn't be running more than a couple of queries like this on a page: if you want to get many `GameNodes` you need to get them in a single query:

```
GameNode.objects.filter(<criteria>)
```

Or if the `GameNode` objects are related to some other object by a foreign key on another model that you are querying, then you could fetch all the related `GameNode` objects by using Django's [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) method.

There's almost always a way to speed things up ([see this testimonial](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2011/12/15/django-optimization-story-thousand-times-faster/)) but we need to know the details before we can say how to do it.